# Android studio did not refactor the support classes in .java and .xml files after refactoring to androidx

Tags: java, android, gradle, androidx

I've tried to migrate the project to androidx and when I clicked refactor-> Migrate to Androidx, it runs a dialog for a few seconds, checking drawable, v4 etc. and stops, but in my project, I'm still left with the older v7 versions in the .java files and things that start with "android.support.v7" in the .xml layout files
Is there any option to automate this process?

Comment: Did you click on refractor in bottom dialog??

Comment: Yes of course, I actually had to refactor the packages in .java files manually.

Comment: One other problem is that after this refactoring, the LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL had to be changed to RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL. This was weird, as google said you don't have to change anything but package names

Answer (score 0):

When you migrate to the Androidx it tells you that It needs to refractor some files. It is not clearly shown. When you will click on migrate to androidx at the bottom Android studio will ask you about do refractor. Click on that it will convert all your files.

Comment: When I clicked on it again, it ran it's dialog again, and then said "No Usages Found in the Project"

Comment: I'm manually refactoring all the RecyclerViews and CardViews again